# toast not working and also else if

Tags: authentication, if-statement, alert, android-toast

In this code `else if` part is not working . `toast` is not appearing if login failed .

my code

```
try {
    s= json.getString("info");
    Log.d("Msg", json.getString("info"));
    if(s.equals("success")) {
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainPage.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);                    
        finish();            
    } else if(s.equals("fail")) { 
        Toast.makeText(getParent(),"Login Failed",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.user)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd)).setText("");
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
Toast.makeText(getParent(),"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: i have written this coding under AsyncTask so toast not working                       private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>

Comment: there is any other way to display login failed . other then toast